# Linking a filetype to a syntax file of a different name

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I’ve created a new filetype, “usenet,” for Usenet messages. I would like files with this filetype to be highlighted exactly as if they had the “mail” filetype. Is it possible to tell Vim that I want to reuse the existing “mail” syntax definitions for this other filetype?

#### What I’ve tried

- I tried writing `setlocal syntax=mail` in the `ftplugin/usenet.vim` file but this seemed to be ignored—running `:set syntax?` in a file with the “usenet” filetype just produced `usenet`.
- I also tried copying the `mail.vim` syntax file from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax` into `~/.vim/syntax`, renaming it to `usenet.vim`, and changing the line

  ```
  let b:current_syntax = "mail"
  ```

  to

  ```
  let b:current_syntax = "usenet"
  ```

  This worked, but if a future version of Vim improves the `mail.vim` file then I would have to go through this process again (and it’s unlikely that I would even notice such a change in the first place). What I want, semantically, is to highlight “usenet” files as if they were “mail” files, which seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `syntax/usenet.vim` with the contents:

```
" Quit when a syntax file was already loaded
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

runtime! syntax/mail.vim
let b:current_syntax = "usenet"
```

In short, just source the file you want to inherit syntax from. If you want any customizations for `usenet`, just make them after you've sourced `syntax/mail.vim`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple filetype names separated with `.`

```
# in your personal filetype.vim
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.usenet setfiletype mail.usenet
augroup END
```

All `mail` filetype plugins and syntax files will be applied before `usenet` filetype plugins and syntax files. All `mail` related stuff (`abbreviations`, `snippets`, balabalas) should work in `usenet`.